# Using shared libraries on a PiCloud environment server

Tags: python, linux, cloud

Linux newbie question: I have a personal [PiCloud](http://www.picloud.com) environment and can install my own Python extensions. But I would like to use a pre-compiled C shared library (mylib.so), i.e., place it in /user/lib. Is that possible? If I have to build it on the PiCloud environment server, how do I upload the source?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible that you could simply copy mylib.so to your environment's /usr/lib. But, it's preferred that you compile mylib.so on the setup server to ensure that all the dependencies are available on the server, and that the correct architecture is used (AMD64).

Here are the steps:

1. Create an environment, and put it in modification mode.
2. You will need to copy your files to the setup server for the environment. If you're on Linux, it'll be easiest to use scp. If you're on Windows, you'll need to use something like [Tunnelier](http://www.bitvise.com/tunnelier). On either OS, you'll need to click on the key icon, and download the SSH Identity file you'll need to authenticate with the setup server for copying files.

   $ scp -i picloud_rsa mylib.tar.gz picloud@setup-server-hostname.com:~/
3. Once the files are on the server, you can either SSH into the setup server, or use the web browser console (new feature!). From there, run your compile scripts. You can copy your .so file to /usr/lib. Don't forget to use "sudo".

   $ sudo cp mylib.so /usr/lib
4. You should run whatever program depends on mylib.so on the setup server to ensure it's working properly. If you're going to run a test, you'll need to run "ldconfig" so that your shared library is in the library cache.

   $ sudo ldconfig

   $ ./run_your_program

Comment: Instead of Tunnelier, you might want to use [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) which more than just free for individual use.